# If condition using Python

Tags: python, tabular

Could you please help me generating third column from the table using Python? I tried with numpy.where option, but I am unable to get the desired output.

My table:

[image: my table]

I have tried the code

```
 db['Condition'] = numpy.where(db.Value <50, 'Less than 50', db.Value <100, 'Less than 100','more than 100').
```

Here, db refers to data base name. And the error message I am getting

> TypeError: where() takes at most 3 arguments (5 given)

Comment: Please provide [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show your current attempt and error messages.

Comment: Hi, Thanking you very much for the comment. I have tried the code db['Condition'] = numpy.where(db.Value <50, 'Less than 50', db.Value <100, 'Less than 100','more than 100'). Here, db refers to data base name. And the error message I am getting  TypeError: where() takes at most 3 arguments (5 given)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [numpy.where](https://www.numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) documentation, it only takes 3 arguments, condition and x (if true),y (if false) array_like. To get your desired output:

```
db['Condition'] = numpy.where(db['Value'] < 50, 'Less than 50', numpy.where(db['Value']<100, 'Less than 100','More than 100'))
```

Comment: Thanking you very much Ricky